# How can I count the number of elements in a vector that fall within a particular range using r?

Tags: r

Let's say we a vector `a = (10,23,57,37,59,25,63,33)` and we want to calculate the frequency in the bins `10-19,20-29,30-39,40-49,50-59,60-69`.The output should be in the form of a vector, in this case `(1,2,2,2,1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Another base R solution is to use `hist`, i.e.,

```
hist(a,plot = FALSE,breaks = seq(10,70,by=10))$counts
# [1] 1 2 2 0 2 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
a <- c(10, 23, 57, 37, 59, 25, 63, 33)
low_val  <- 10
high_val <- 70
a_breaks <- seq(low_val, high_val, 10)
res <- cut(a, a_breaks, include.lowest = T)
as.vector(table(res))
[1] 1 2 2 0 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `cut` with `table`

```
table(cut(a, breaks = c(-Inf, seq(10, 70, by = 10), Inf)))
```

---

Or another option is

```
table(findInterval, seq(10, 70, by = 10)))
```